# Append to end of list if element matches element in list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of lists in which I want to match the `[3]` element in each nested list to the `[1]` element in another set of lists generated from a for loop. The `[1]` element should be appended to each nested list of lists if there is a match.

```
unique_data = [[98764, 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 687'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 689'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 555']
```

Student count generated for each course from a `for` loop:

```
['SSW 555', 1]
['SSW 689', 1]
['SSW 687', 3]
```

Could a good approach be generating a list of lists from the student counts?

This approach (where `coursecount` is each one of the generated lists):

```
for i in unique_data:
    if coursecount[0] == [el[3] for el in unique_data]:
        unique_data.append(coursecount[1])
```

Doesn't work because `[el[3] for el in unique_data]` results in a printout of a list of all the courses, which of course is not going to match a single value. End desired result would be something like:

```
[98764, 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 687', 3]
[98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 689', 1]
[98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 555', 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coursecount` looks like a list of lists. This data structure isn't very efficient if you want to look up things from it. You'd be better off converting this to a dictionary.

```
coursecount = [['SSW 555', 1], ['SSW 689', 1], ['SSW 687', 3]]
coursecount_dict = {a: b for a, b in coursecount}
# Or simply, you could do
# coursecount_dict = dict(coursecount)
# because coursecount is a Nx2 list of key-value pairs
```

Now `coursecount_dict` is

```
{'SSW 555': 1, 'SSW 689': 1, 'SSW 687': 3}
```

You can look up values in a dictionary using the key much, *much* faster than you can look up items in a list-of-lists. For example, to get the value for `'SSW 687'`, all you'd need to do is `coursecount_dict['SSW 687']`. This is an O(1) operation because of the way dictionaries work. If you used a list-of-lists, this would be an O(n) operation because you'd have to iterate over all the courses to find the one that matched.

Then, you want to loop over `unique_data`, get the correct item from the dictionary, and append it to the list in `unique_data`. You can append it in-place.

```
unique_data = [[98764, 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 687'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 689'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 555']]

for item in unique_data:
    coursename = item[3]
    students = coursecount_dict.get(coursename, 0) 
    # students becomes coursecount_dict[coursename], 0 if not exists
    item.append(students)
```

Now `unique_data` becomes:

```
[[98764, 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 687', 3],
 [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 689', 1],
 [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 555', 1]]
```

Comment: That did the trick! I had `coursecount` defined as a key: value pair with a list of lists for some reason, so just switched that to a dictionary in my initial definition. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
result_list=[] 
for i in unique_data:
    if coursecount[0] == i[3]:
        Result_list.extend(i.append(coursecount[1]))
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, but I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

This sample produces what you wanted:

```
listsss = [['SSW 555', 1], ['SSW 689', 1], ['SSW 687', 3]]
unique_data = [[98764, 'Feynman, R', 'SFEN', 'SSW 687'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 689'], [98763, 'Newton, I', 'SFEN', 'SSW 555']]
    
for coursecount in listsss:
    for element in unique_data:
        if coursecount[0] == element[3]:
            element.append(coursecount[1])
print(unique_data)
```